# Python: finding index of all elements of array in another including repeating arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A of size 100 which might have repeating elements in it. I have another array B of size 10 which have unique elements in it. All elements of B are present in A and vice versa. I have another array C corresponding to B where each element of C is corresponding to the element in B.

I want to create an array A2 composed of elements of C, such that I can achieve the following:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,1,4,5,5,6])
B = np.array([4,6,5,1)])
C = np.array(['A','B','C','D')])
```

I want to create A2 such that:

```
A2 = np.array(['D','D','A','C','C','B'])
```

A2 has elements from C based on matching index of elements of B in A.

Comment: Does it have to be numpy? Plain old Python seems more than enough to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `numpy`. Just `zip` the `B` and `C` arrays to a `dict` and `map` the values of `A`:

```
>>> btoc = dict(zip(B, C))
>>> A2 = np.array(map(btoc.get, A))
>>> A2
array(['D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'], dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPythonic approach using [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
sidx = B.argsort()
out = C[sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A,sorter = sidx)]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: A = np.array([1,1,4,5,5,6])
    ...: B = np.array([4,6,5,1])
    ...: C = np.array(['A','B','C','D'])
    ...: 

In [18]: sidx = B.argsort()

In [19]: C[sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A,sorter = sidx)]]
Out[19]: 
array(['D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to do this in a single call; npi.indices, which is a vectorized equivalent of list.index.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,1,4,5,5,6])
B = np.array([4,6,5,1])
C = np.array(['A','B','C','D'])

import numpy_indexed as npi
i = npi.indices(B, A)
print(C[i])
```

Performance should be similar to the solution of Divakar, since it operates along the same lines; but all wrapped up in a convenient package with tests and all.

Comment: pip install numpy_indexed gives error: no module named yaml

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but strange; I thought id fixed that already... running pip install pyyaml first should fix that though.